# Ng serve throwing errors related to node_modules/@angular/core/core that has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

I tried running a legacy project which is supposed to work with Angular 8 version but I get a bunch of errors related to node_modules that some code (e.g ɵɵFactoryDeclaration) is not exported:

[image]
[image]

I believe that some dependency has the wrong version but I couldn't identify which.. This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "greenhouse-designer-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4200",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.11",
    "@ctrl/ngx-codemirror": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.5.1",
    "@types/fabric": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/npm": "^2.0.31",
    "angular-split": "^4.0.0",
    "codemirror": "^5.49.2",
    "fabric": "^3.4.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.6",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.1.2",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.7",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.2",
    "@babel/compat-data": "7.8.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.7",
    "ts-node": "^6.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.19.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  }
}
```

I am using node v14.21.3, npm v6.14.18. I tried deleting node_modules and clearing the cache but it seems to not work...

Also I install my dependencies with --legacy-peer-deps flag

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Node: 14.21.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.29
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.29
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.29
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.29
@schematics/angular               8.3.29
@schematics/update                0.803.29
rxjs                              6.6.7
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this in your package.json and then run `npm i`:

`"@ngxs/store": "~3.7.6"`

Comment: I tried this but I get the same errors. with a fresh install

Comment: then try `"@ngxs/store": "~3.5.1"` - tilde instead of ceret

Comment: The tilde approach worked! Thank you very much!